# Does the Euler constant allow to go from the prime realm to the zeta zeros realm?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, prime-gaps

On average the $n$-th critical zero of the Riemann zeta function has imaginary part around $\frac{2\pi n}{\log n}$, so that the average gap between the $n$-th and $n+1$-th zero is $\frac{2\pi}{\log n}$. That way, the reciprocal thereof is the average prime gap $g_{n}:=p_{n+1}-p_{n}$.

Taking into account the critical zeros of zeta of negative imaginary part, computations on wolfram alpha lead to this:

$$\displaystyle{\dfrac{4\pi\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\Im(\rho_{k+1}-\rho_{k})}}{n}-\gamma\approx\dfrac{p_{n+1}-2}{n}+\gamma}$$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.

So my questions are:

1) does the difference between thd LHS and the RHS tend to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$?

2) if yes to 1), does $x\mapsto x+\gamma$ play an analogous role to $g_n\mapsto\frac{2\pi}{g_n}$ as an additive factor to add to go from the prime gap realm to the zeta zero gap realm? Or more philosophically from the discrete realm of integers to the continuous realm of real numbers?

Comment: You are aware that the RHS has an asymptotic given by the PNT, with remainder $O(1/\log^r n)$ ? The gap between the zeros is complicated, don't expect any proven result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Mathematica program to plot the LHS and RHS for the 49 first terms of n:

```
nn = 50
g1 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[4*Pi*Sum[1/(aa[[k + 1]] - aa[[k]]), {k, 1, n}]/n - 
     EulerGamma, {n, 1, nn - 1}]];
g2 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[(Prime[n + 1] - 2)/n + EulerGamma, {n, 1, nn - 1}]];
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image: plot of comparison of 50 first zeta zeros]

And here is a Mathematica program to plot the LHS and RHS for the 10000-1 first terms of n:

```
nn = 10000
g1 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[4*Pi*Sum[1/(aa[[k + 1]] - aa[[k]]), {k, 1, n}]/n - 
     EulerGamma, {n, 1, nn - 1}]];
g2 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[(Prime[n + 1] - 2)/n + EulerGamma, {n, 1, nn - 1}]];
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image: 10000-1 first terms of n]